# bootstrap navbar open on first click and go to link on second click

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using the bootstrap 3 navbar with drop down. Default is behaviour is on click open dropdown and on second click close. I want to visit the link on second click. Is that posible whith default bootstap functionality>

Comment: you need to use jquery for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.open').removeClass('open').find('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
    $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle').removeAttr('data-toggle');
});
```

This will toggle the dropdown open on the first click, while closing any other open dropdowns. If you click the parent of the open dropdown menu again it will navigate to it's href. If you toggle a different dropdown it will "reset" any dropdowns that were open so that you can re-toggle them again.